# Transactions Not working properly in insert query

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

So i'm trying to run an query by using a transaction but it's not working somehow i did check all the posts but no fixes seems to be working ! whenever i remove the transaction the insert query works just fine.

Here's the controller :

```
public function addEmployee(){
        $field = array(
            'NomClient'=>$this->input->post('fullName'),
            'TelClient'=>$this->input->post('tel'),
            'WilayaClient'=>$this->input->post('wilaya'),
            'CommuneClient'=>$this->input->post('commune'),
            'AdresseClient'=>$this->input->post('adresse'),
            'StatusID'=>$this->input->post('statusCommande'),
            'TelevendeuseID'=>$this->input->post('televendeuse')
            );
        $result= $this->m->addEmployee($field);
        $msg['success'] = false;
        $msg['type'] = 'add';
        if($result){
            $msg['success'] = true;
        }
        echo json_encode($msg);

    }
```

My model :

```
public function addEmployee($field){

         $this->db->trans_start();
         return $this->db->insert('Clients',$field);
         $this->db->trans_complete();

    }
```

Please note that when i switch the model to :

```
    public function addEmployee($field){


         return $this->db->insert('Clients',$field);


    }
```

The record gets inserted successfully ! Which means that something is wrong with the transaction. I'm currently using one query to test if it's working so i can use multiples onces after that. Note that the tables are InnoDB tables so the problem isn't with the table type. Please help me out !

Comment: Why do you use transactions at all when you're just making one single query? Seems kind of pointless?

Comment: You have a `return` before your `$this->db->trans_complete();`, so it will never be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `return` it will end the function, so when it hits

```
return $this->db->insert('Clients',$field);
```

it will not get to

```
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

so perhaps...

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$return = $this->db->insert('Clients',$field);
$this->db->trans_complete();

return $return;
```

Comment: I have a question , what if i have multiple inserts , is it's possible to return multiple variables? or should i append them to an array?

Comment: You will have to think about what you are returning, if you need to check if each SQL has worked or do you just assume that everything works.  You also will need to think about when (if at all) you may want to rollback the transaction.

Comment: I'd like to use returns to check if all the records have been inserted ! for a single insert a single return is right but what if i have multiple inserts and i want to check if they have returned true?

Comment: Not a huge fan of this type of coding, but it is short - use the return from the previous command to flag subsequent commands - `$return = $return && $this->db->insert('Clients',$field);` it's basically short cuts the command if `$return` is false.

Comment: okok thanks a lot ! what do you think of using the list feature in php > 7.1?